# How to speed OpenCV createMergeMertens function?

Tags: c++, opencv, pthreads

I fusion multiexposure image from videostream in thread (pthread):

```
vector<Mat> images;

images.push_back(cv::Mat(displayContext->imageLowExposure->height(),displayContext->imageLowExposure->width(),
                         CV_8UC1,displayContext->imageLowExposure->bits(),displayContext->imageLowExposure->bytesPerLine()));
images.push_back(cv::Mat(displayContext->imageMediumExposure->height(),displayContext->imageMediumExposure->width(),
                         CV_8UC1,displayContext->imageMediumExposure->bits(),displayContext->imageMediumExposure->bytesPerLine()));
images.push_back(cv::Mat(displayContext->imageHighExposure->height(),displayContext->imageHighExposure->width(),
                         CV_8UC1,displayContext->imageHighExposure->bits(),displayContext->imageHighExposure->bytesPerLine()));

Mat exposureFusion;
Ptr<MergeMertens> mergeMertens = createMergeMertens();
mergeMertens->process(images, exposureFusion);

Mat convert;
exposureFusion.convertTo(convert,CV_8UC1,255);

QImage temp (convert.data, convert.cols, convert.rows, convert.step, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);

for (int i = 0; i < displayContext->height; ++i){
    memcpy(displayContext->resultImage->scanLine(i),temp.scanLine(i),size_t(displayContext->resultImage->width()));
}
```

This code give good result, resultImage with good quality. But but in the end the video speed is reduced to 5 fps.If comment createMergeMertens() function, video speed is normal - 30 fps. How to speed OpenCV createMergeMertens function? At runtime in htop app only one core 100%, other core not above 30%. How to load all CPU cores? Maybe i can use GPU on my video card NVIDIA 1060? My system - UBUNTU 19.04, QT 5.12.6, Intel® Core™ i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4,OpenCV 4.

Comment: The code of that function is not optimized with ipp or cuda  so maybe you need  to implement it . https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/photo/src/merge.cpp

Comment: are you sure that this part of your code is the slowest ? (mergeMertens->process(images, exposureFusion);)

Comment: After commenting out this function - mergeMertens->process(images, exposureFusion). Cpu was getting unloaded.